# Xlib. Redraw (refill) flickering shaped window after resize

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib

I have class which implements flickering border (it changes it's color every 0.5 seconds). Everything works fine until the border is resized. When I resize border only part of the border continues to flicker. I guess, that the problem somewhere in my Expose event handler or in resize function, but I can't find where exactly.
Main program starts separate thread for creating border. Border is controlled from main thread:

```
#include "LinuxBorderWindow.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

#define W_WIDTH 640
#define W_HEIGHT 480

#define X_POS 100
#define Y_POS 120
#define BORDER_WIDTH 2

LinuxBorderWindow* border;

void threadFunc()
{
    border->SetPosition(X_POS, Y_POS, X_POS + W_WIDTH, Y_POS + W_HEIGHT);
    border->Start();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    border = new LinuxBorderWindow();

    std::thread(threadFunc).detach();

    int choice = 0;
    bool isExit = false;
    while(!isExit)
    {
        std::cout << "Input action" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            border->MoveBorder(X_POS + 100, Y_POS + 200);
            break;
        case 2:
            border->ResizeBorder(X_POS + 100, Y_POS + 200, W_WIDTH - 100, W_HEIGHT + 200);
            break;
        case 3:
            border->ResizeBorder(0, 0, W_WIDTH + 100, W_HEIGHT + 200);
            break;
        case 4:
            border->ShowBorder(false);
            break;
        case 5:
            border->ShowBorder(true);
            break;
        case 0:
            isExit = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    delete border;

    return 0;
}
```

As it seen from the code, resize function is called when choice is 2 or 3. In this case border stops flickering correctly.

Here is the border class:

```
#pragma once

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>
#include <X11/extensions/shape.h>

class LinuxBorderWindow
{
public:
    LinuxBorderWindow();
    ~LinuxBorderWindow();

    void Start();
    void Stop();
    void ShowBorder(bool show);
    void MoveBorder(int x, int y);
    void SetPosition(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void ResizeBorder(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void UpdateRegionSizeAndPos();

private:
    void CreateBorder();

    XRectangle m_windowRect;
    short unsigned int m_borderThickness;

    Window m_window;
    Display* m_display;

    XColor _darkOrangeColor;
    XColor _lightOrangeColor;

    bool m_highlightFrame = false;
};
```

And .cpp file:

```
#include "LinuxBorderWindow.h"
#include <thread>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <cmath>

static int wait_fd(int fd, double seconds)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set in_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&in_fds);
    FD_SET(fd, &in_fds);
    tv.tv_sec = trunc(seconds);
    tv.tv_usec = (seconds - trunc(seconds))*1000000;
    return select(fd+1, &in_fds, 0, 0, &tv);
}

int XNextEventTimeout(Display *display, XEvent *event, double seconds)
{
    if (XPending(display) || wait_fd(ConnectionNumber(display),seconds))
    {
        XNextEvent(display, event);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

constexpr short frameThickness = 2;

void LinuxBorderWindow::CreateBorder()
{
    GC gc;
    XGCValues gcv = {0};

    Window defaultRootWindow = DefaultRootWindow(m_display);

    m_window = XCreateSimpleWindow(m_display, defaultRootWindow, m_windowRect.x, m_windowRect.y,
                               m_windowRect.width, m_windowRect.height, m_borderThickness, 0, _darkOrangeColor.pixel);
    gcv.line_width = m_borderThickness;
    gc = XCreateGC(m_display, m_window, GCLineWidth, &gcv);

    XSelectInput(m_display, m_window, ExposureMask);
    Atom window_type = XInternAtom(m_display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    long value = XInternAtom(m_display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);
    XChangeProperty(m_display, m_window, window_type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &value, 1);
    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(m_display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(m_display, m_window, &wm_delete_window, 1);
    XRectangle rectangles[4] =
    {
        { 0, 0, m_windowRect.width, m_borderThickness },
        { 0, 0, m_borderThickness, m_windowRect.height },
        { 0, (short)(m_windowRect.height - m_borderThickness), m_windowRect.width, m_borderThickness },
        { (short)(m_windowRect.width - m_borderThickness), 0, m_borderThickness, m_windowRect.height }
    };
    XserverRegion region = XFixesCreateRegion(m_display, rectangles, 4);
    XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(m_display, m_window, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, region);
    XMapWindow(m_display, m_window);
    XFlush(m_display);
    XSync(m_display, False);

    //std::thread([this, gc]
    {
        bool run = true;
        while(run)
        {
            XEvent xe;
            if(::XNextEventTimeout(m_display, &xe, 0.5))
            {
                m_highlightFrame = !m_highlightFrame;
                xe.type = Expose;
                xe.xexpose.count = 0;
            }
            switch (xe.type)
            {
                case Expose:
                {
                    XSetForeground(m_display, gc, m_highlightFrame ? _lightOrangeColor.pixel : _darkOrangeColor.pixel);
                    XFillRectangles(m_display, m_window, gc, rectangles, 4);
                    XSync(m_display, False);
                    break;
                }
                case ClientMessage:
                {
                    if (xe.xclient.message_type == XInternAtom(m_display, "WM_PROTOCOLS", 1)
                    && (Atom)xe.xclient.data.l[0] == XInternAtom(m_display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 1))
                    {
                        run = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }//).detach();
}

LinuxBorderWindow::LinuxBorderWindow()
{
    m_borderThickness = ::frameThickness;

    m_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    char orangeDark[] = "#FF8000";
    char orangeLight[] = "#FFC90E";
    Colormap colormap = DefaultColormap(m_display, 0);
    XParseColor(m_display, colormap, orangeDark, &_darkOrangeColor);
    XAllocColor(m_display, colormap, &_darkOrangeColor);
    XParseColor(m_display, colormap, orangeLight, &_lightOrangeColor);
    XAllocColor(m_display, colormap, &_lightOrangeColor);
}

LinuxBorderWindow::~LinuxBorderWindow()
{
    if(m_display != NULL)
    {
        Stop();
        XCloseDisplay(m_display);
    }
}

void LinuxBorderWindow::Start()
{
    CreateBorder();
}

void LinuxBorderWindow::Stop()
{
    XWindowAttributes xwa;
    XGetWindowAttributes(m_display, m_window, &xwa);
    if(xwa.map_state == IsViewable)
    {
        XUnmapWindow(m_display, m_window);
        XDestroyWindow(m_display, m_window);
    }
}

void LinuxBorderWindow::SetPosition(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    m_windowRect.x = (short)x1;
    m_windowRect.y = (short)y1;
    m_windowRect.width = (unsigned short)(x2 - x1);
    m_windowRect.height = (unsigned short)(y2 - y1);
}


void LinuxBorderWindow::ShowBorder(bool show)
{
    XWindowAttributes xwa;
    XGetWindowAttributes(m_display, m_window, &xwa);

    if(show && xwa.map_state != IsViewable)
    {
        XMapWindow(m_display, m_window);
    }
    else if(show == false && xwa.map_state == IsViewable)
    {
        XUnmapWindow(m_display, m_window);
    }
}
void LinuxBorderWindow::MoveBorder(int x, int y)
{
    m_windowRect.x = (short)x;
    m_windowRect.y = (short)y;
    XMoveWindow(m_display, m_window, x, y);
}

void LinuxBorderWindow::ResizeBorder(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    SetPosition(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    XMoveResizeWindow(m_display, m_window, m_windowRect.x, m_windowRect.y, m_windowRect.width, m_windowRect.height);
    XRectangle rectangles[4] =
    {
        { 0, 0, m_windowRect.width, m_borderThickness },
        { 0, 0, m_borderThickness, m_windowRect.height },
        { 0, (short)(m_windowRect.height - m_borderThickness), m_windowRect.width, m_borderThickness },
        { (short)(m_windowRect.width - m_borderThickness), 0, m_borderThickness, m_windowRect.height }
    };
    XserverRegion region = XFixesCreateRegion(m_display, rectangles, 4);
    XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(m_display, m_window, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, region);
}
```

So my main question is how to make flicker all border after resize, but not only one part? And additional question is how to hide/show window (ShowBorder method), because XUnmapWindow/XMapWindow doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> flicker all border after resize

Make `XRectangle rectangles[4]` a class field. No wonder it starts behaving weird, for the 'flicker' function continues using the old rectangle even after the new one has been applied to the window.

> how to hide/show window

This one is trickier.

X11 library is not thread safe. This is why all sorts of weird things may happen when you try to operate on one window from different threads. Generally, your `std::thread`-based approach is not the correct way of managing an X11 message loop.

This is a more X11-compliant app doing the same thing:

```cpp
#include "LinuxBorderWindow.h"
#include <sys/poll.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    enum {
        W_WIDTH = 640,
        W_HEIGHT = 480,
        X_POS = 100,
        Y_POS = 120,
        BORDER_WIDTH = 4,
        MSEC_DELAY = 500,
    };

    Display *m_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    struct pollfd fd = { ConnectionNumber(m_display), POLLIN };

    LinuxBorderWindow *border =
        new LinuxBorderWindow(m_display, BORDER_WIDTH, X_POS, Y_POS,
                              X_POS + W_WIDTH, Y_POS + W_HEIGHT);
    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        if (!XPending(m_display) && !poll(&fd, 1, MSEC_DELAY)) {
            border->BlinkBorder();
            continue;
        }
        XEvent xe = {0};
        XNextEvent(m_display, &xe);
        switch (xe.type) {
        case Expose:
            break;

        case KeyRelease:
            switch (XLookupKeysym(&xe.xkey, 0)) {
            case '1':
                border->ResizeBorder(X_POS + 100, Y_POS + 200);
                break;
            case '2':
                border->ResizeBorder(X_POS + 100, Y_POS + 200,
                                     W_WIDTH - 100, W_HEIGHT + 200);
                break;
            case '3':
                border->ResizeBorder(0, 0, W_WIDTH + 100, W_HEIGHT + 200);
                break;
            case '4':
                border->ShowBorder(false);
                break;
            case '5':
                border->ShowBorder(true);
                break;
            case '0':
                run = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    delete border;
    return XCloseDisplay(m_display);
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <climits>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/extensions/shape.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>

class LinuxBorderWindow {
public:
    LinuxBorderWindow(Display *display, short frameThickness,
                      int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    ~LinuxBorderWindow();
    Window GetWindow() { return m_window; }

    void BlinkBorder();
    void ShowBorder(bool show);
    void ResizeBorder(int x1, int y1, int x2 = INT_MAX, int y2 = INT_MAX);

private:
    XColor m_darkOrangeColor;
    XColor m_lightOrangeColor;
    XRectangle m_windowRect;
    unsigned short m_borderThickness;

    bool m_highlightFrame = false;
    Display *m_display = nullptr;
    Window m_window = 0;
};
```

```cpp
#include "LinuxBorderWindow.h"



static void SetAtom(Display *disp, Window hwnd, int mode,
                    const char *name, const char *atom) {
    Atom prop = XInternAtom(disp, atom, false);
    XChangeProperty(disp, hwnd, XInternAtom(disp, name, false),
                    XA_ATOM, 32, mode, (unsigned char *)&prop, 1);
}



LinuxBorderWindow::LinuxBorderWindow
(Display *display, short frameThickness, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
: m_display(display), m_borderThickness(frameThickness) {
    Colormap colormap = DefaultColormap(m_display, 0);
    XParseColor(m_display, colormap, "#FF8000", &m_darkOrangeColor);
    XParseColor(m_display, colormap, "#FFC90E", &m_lightOrangeColor);
    XAllocColor(m_display, colormap, &m_darkOrangeColor);
    XAllocColor(m_display, colormap, &m_lightOrangeColor);

    ResizeBorder(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    m_window = XCreateSimpleWindow(m_display, DefaultRootWindow(m_display),
                                   m_windowRect.x, m_windowRect.y,
                                   m_windowRect.width, m_windowRect.height,
                                   0, 0, m_darkOrangeColor.pixel);
    ShowBorder(true);

    XSelectInput(m_display, m_window, ExposureMask | KeyReleaseMask);

    // TOOLBAR, since _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK does not accept keyboard input
    SetAtom(m_display, m_window, PropModeReplace,
            "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLBAR");

    // compensating for the lack of _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
    SetAtom(m_display, m_window, PropModeReplace,
            "_NET_WM_STATE", "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE");

    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(m_display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(m_display, m_window, &wm_delete_window, 1);

    XMapWindow(m_display, m_window);
    XFlush(m_display);
    XSync(m_display, false);
}



LinuxBorderWindow::~LinuxBorderWindow() {
    if (m_display && m_window) {
        XUnmapWindow(m_display, m_window);
        XDestroyWindow(m_display, m_window);
    }
}



void LinuxBorderWindow::BlinkBorder() {
    XSetWindowBackground(m_display, m_window,
                        (m_highlightFrame = !m_highlightFrame)?
                         m_lightOrangeColor.pixel : m_darkOrangeColor.pixel);
    XClearWindow(m_display, m_window);
}



void LinuxBorderWindow::ShowBorder(bool show) {
    unsigned short thickness = (show)? m_borderThickness : 0;
    XRectangle rectangles[4] = {
        { 0, 0, m_windowRect.width, thickness },
        { 0, 0, thickness, m_windowRect.height },
        { 0, m_windowRect.height - thickness, m_windowRect.width, thickness },
        { m_windowRect.width - thickness, 0, thickness, m_windowRect.height },
    };
    XserverRegion rgn = XFixesCreateRegion(m_display, rectangles, 4);
    XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(m_display, m_window, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, rgn);
    XFixesDestroyRegion(m_display, rgn);
}



void LinuxBorderWindow::ResizeBorder(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    m_windowRect.x = x1;
    m_windowRect.y = y1;
    if (x2 != INT_MAX)
        m_windowRect.width = x2 - x1;
    if (y2 != INT_MAX)
        m_windowRect.height = y2 - y1;
    if (m_window) {
        XMoveResizeWindow(m_display, m_window, m_windowRect.x, m_windowRect.y,
                          m_windowRect.width, m_windowRect.height);
        ShowBorder(true);
    }
}
```